# Existence of set $B=\{x\in A\mid x\notin f(x)\}$ in Cantor's theorem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the proof in wiki:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem
$B=\{x\in A\mid x\notin f(x)\}$
Example, where $B$ does NOT exist:
$A=\{a,b\}$
$P(A)=\{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\emptyset\}$
Possible correspondence:
$a\leftrightarrow \{a\}$,
$b\leftrightarrow \{b\}$
So, $B$ does not always exist. So, the proof does not always work.

Comment: If $A$ has three elements, then $\mathcal P(A)$ must have $2^3=8$ elements.

Comment: A={a,b} P(A)={{a},{b},{a,b},{∅}} Possible correspondence: a⟷{a}, b⟷{b}, -⟷{∅}, -⟷{a,b}

Comment: A={a,b} P(A)={{a},{b},{a,b},{∅}} Possible correspondence: a⟷{a}, b⟷{b}. So, there is no such that B={x∈A|x∉f(x)}

Comment: Or another question: if A={∅}, then P(A)={{∅}}. So ∅⟷{∅}. So, B=B={x∈A|x∉f(x)} does not exist. Because {∅} contains ∅

Comment: @JosefKlimuk No, if $A=\{\emptyset\}$, $P(A)$ also contains $\emptyset$ which is not in the  image of the correspondence, and indeed $B=\emptyset$ so it checks out. You seem to confuse the empty set with a non-existent set; this is nonsense, the empty set does exist.

Comment: Also in your post example, $B=\emptyset$, also not in the image of the correspondence. The proof works.

Comment: I don't understand this: if A is empty (A=∅), then P(A)={{∅}, ∅}. ∅ of A can correspond to {∅} in P(A), and since there is no members in A, but only ∅, all members of A can correspond to subsets of P(A), which contain these members of A.

Comment: In that example there does not exist $x$ such that $x\notin f(x)$. That does not say $B$ does not exist, it just says $B$ is empty.

Comment: But all members of B are members of A. If B=empty set, then it is the same empty set in A (because there cannot be two distinct empty set in A) to which we already paired {∅} in P(A).

Answer (score 1):

The powerset of $A$ is $\{\emptyset, A, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{\emptyset\}, \{a,b\}, \{a, \emptyset\}, \{b, \emptyset\}\}$, which has $8$ elements as $3$ has three.

And given $f$ the set $B$ always exists by the axioms of set theory, it is not ensured to be non-empty though, but the empty set does *exist*. We only need a set that is not in the image of $f$, and this set could well be $\emptyset$, which is always a member of the powerset of any set.

Comment: Since ∅ is a subset of every set, A={a,b} also contains ∅.  So, P(A)={{a}, {b},{a,∅},{b,∅}, {a,b},{a,b,∅},{∅}}. So, P(A) will have 7 members, so the rule: P(A)=2^A will not work.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk $\emptyset$ is indeed a *subset* of each set, so an *element* of each powerset. You are removing it as an element. If $A=\{a,b\}$ it’s subsets are $\emptyset, \{a\},,\{b\},A$, so four subsets. You have some misconceptions about the powerset.

Comment: What does it mean: "You are removing it as an element"? ∅ will be always in A, so will take part in formation of all A's subsets, which is P(A)

Comment: @JosefKlimuk in your $P(A)$ (comment above) you don’t mention $\emptyset$ as an element.

Comment: I got it. So, if A={a,b}, A has really three members {a,b,∅}? Once I read a textbook, where A was set as {a,b} and it was written there that it contains two members. They missed to count ∅?

Comment: @JosefKlimuk no, there are two members. But $\emptyset$ is a **subset** of $A$ so an **element** of $P(A)$.

Comment: One more questions: what about the situation when A=∅? All members of B are members of A. If B=empty set, then it is the same empty set in A (because there cannot be two distinct empty set in A) to which we already paired {∅} in P(A).

Comment: If $A= \emptyset$ (no elements), then $P(A) = \{\emptyset\}$ (one element). There is clearly no correspondence from $A$ onto $P(A)$, there are no "originals".

Comment: What about? ∅⟷{∅}

Comment: No, you misunderstand what a correspondence is. $\emptyset$ is not an **element** of $A$, so it has no "image". A correspondence from $A$ to $B$ is a set of pairs $(x,y)$ where for each $x \in A$ there is a unique $y \in B$ so that $(x,y)$ is in that correspondence. Here we have no elements in $A$, so the correspondence set is empty. So it has no sets in its image either.

Comment: And why ∅  is not an element of A?